# Mac - Monitoring file moves / renames

Tags: macos, cocoa, file, file-io

I'm considering creating a file manager that keeps track of files on a user's system, but stores its metadata separately.

Is there a way to detect if a user moves a file *outside of my application* (or while my application isn't running) to know where the file moved to?  For example, if a user has a photo stored in `~/Desktop/pictures` (and my database has this as an entry), and they move it to `~/Documents/My Pictures`, I'd like to be able to keep a reference to it still - is there a way to do this?  Similarly, if they rename the file, I'd like to know it's the same file.

In other words - can you ask the system to notify you of changes to files' names and paths?  **Is there an application-accessible identifier for files which contains the proper reference irrespective of its actual name or path?**

I'm new to the Cocoa API on the desktop; I'm one of those who learned Obj-C on iPhone programming and would like to apply it to the desktop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes: it's called ["bookmark data"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURL/bookmarkDataWithContentsOfURL:error:), and has existed in this form since Mac OS X 10.6. If you need to use it on older version, you're looking for the [Alias Manager](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/Alias_Manager/Reference/reference.html).

Comment: Wow, this... looks pretty good.  Can I write these bookmarks to disk as part of a database and later retrieve them, or are the bookmarks only good for a certain period of time?

Comment: Yep, it's completely persistable. There are a few things that can break the bookmark, but not very many, and you can stick them in a database just fine.

Comment: Do you know what things can break it?  And a bonus question for you - where do I look to accept drag and drop files onto my application?

Comment: Also, I'll just stick with Bookmark data.  I'm not really interested in supporting 10.5 and earlier.

Comment: Confuse the file system and you'll confuse the bookmark. For example, moving a file from one volume to another will usually do it. Also note that the bookmark system, unless told otherwise, will prefer to use a "different" file with the same name in the same spot over the "same" file in a different location. As for drag-and-drop: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DragandDrop/DragandDrop.html